# can not make webpack work with uglify

Tags: webpack, silverstripe, webpack-2, uglifyjs

I use webpack and it was working sweet up to a few days ago.

on `npm run build` I get an error
`npm run dev` and 
`npm run watch` 
work fine.

```
ERROR in bundle.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: punc (() [bundle.js:20892,36]

ERROR in bundle.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: punc (() [bundle.js:20892,36]
```

I use the following webpack setup:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ss-webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A silverstripe theme setup using webpack to bundle assets and provide a front end build system. ",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dashboard -- webpack-dev-server",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development webpack",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --progress"
  },
  "author": "Sunny Side Up",
  "license": "tba",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.5",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
    "eslint": "^4.8.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "normalize.css": "^7.0.0",
    "postcss": "^6.0.13",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.6",
    "postcss-reporter": "^4.0.0",
    "postcss-scss": "^1.0.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "stylelint": "^7.13.0",
    "svg-inline-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "uglify-js": "git+https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2.git#harmony",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dashboard": "^0.4.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.5.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.4",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.2"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.babel.js:

```
/*
 Webpack Config!
 Original version: Andrew Haine
*/

/*
    Imports
*/

import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';
import DashboardPlugin from 'webpack-dashboard/plugin';
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';
import variables from './../webpack-variables';

/*
    Useful constants
*/

const SITE_NAME = variables.devWebAddress;
const THEME_NAME = variables.themeName;
const DISTRIBUTION_FOLDER = variables.distributionFolder;

/*
    Plugin configuration
*/

//different css points
const extractEditor = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: 'editor.css',
});
const extractMain = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: 'style.css',
});

//define plugins
let plugins = [];

const IS_PROD = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

if(IS_PROD) {
    plugins.push(
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
        extractEditor,
        extractMain
    );


//development
} else {
    plugins.push(
        //auto updating on dev server
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        //shows relative path in HotModuleReplacement
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        //sexy dashboard
        new DashboardPlugin(),
        extractEditor
    );
}

plugins.push(new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery"
}))

const sources = [
    `../${THEME_NAME}/src`,
    `../${THEME_NAME}_mysite/src`
];

const sassFolders = sources.map((source) => path.resolve(source, "scss"))
    .concat(sources.map((source) => path.resolve(source, "sass")));

//HMR can be fixed by using basic loaders instead of textExtract
const sassLoaderExtract =    {
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: [
        'css-loader',
        {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
                sourceMap: true
            }
        },
        {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
                sourceMap: true
            }
        },
    ]
}

const styleLoaders = [{
    //basic css
    test: /\.css/i,
    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
}, {
    //main styles
    test: /[^editor].\.s(a|c)ss$/i,
    include: sassFolders,
    use: extractMain.extract(sassLoaderExtract)
}, {
    //styles for editor
    test: /editor\.s(a|c)ss/i,
    include: sassFolders,
    use: extractEditor.extract(sassLoaderExtract)
}];

var jsLoaders = [
    // KEEP THE CODE BELOW AND TURN ON IF NEEDED....
    // {
    //     //eslint check
    //     enforce: 'pre',
    //     test: /\.js$/i,
    //     exclude: /node_modules/,
    //     use: {
    //         loader: 'eslint-loader'
    //     }
    // },
    {
        //js compilation
        test: /\.js$/i,
        include: sources.map((source) => path.resolve(source, "src")),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                cacheDirectory: true,
                presets: [require.resolve("babel-preset-es2015")]
            }
        }
    }
];

if(IS_PROD) {

    jsLoaders.push(
        {
            test: require.resolve('jquery'),
            use: [{
                loader: 'expose-loader',
                options: 'jQuery'
            },{
                loader: 'expose-loader',
                options: '$'
            }]
        }
    );
}

const imageLoaders = [
    {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i,
        use: [
            {
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 30000
                }
            },
            {
                loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                options: {
                    optipng: {
                        optimizationLevel: 5
                    },
                    mozjpeg: {
                        interlaced: true,
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        use: 'svg-inline-loader'
    }
];

/*
    Main Config Object
*/
export default {
    //what files to start from
    //bundle should include main.js from all sources
    entry: path.resolve(`../${THEME_NAME}_mysite/src`, "main.js"),
    //access from client
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(`../${DISTRIBUTION_FOLDER}/`, ''),
        publicPath: `/themes/${DISTRIBUTION_FOLDER}/`,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    //loaders
    module: {
        rules: styleLoaders.concat(jsLoaders).concat(imageLoaders)
    },
    //extra settings
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.join(__dirname, "node_modules"),
            path.resolve(`../${THEME_NAME}_node_modules/node_modules`),
            path.resolve(`../${THEME_NAME}_mysite/node_modules/`)
        ],
        alias: {
            site: path.resolve(`./../../`),
            base: path.resolve(`../${THEME_NAME}/src/`),
            mysite: path.resolve(`../${THEME_NAME}_mysite/src/`),
            'jquery': 'jquery/dist/jquery',
            'jQuery': 'jquery/dist/jquery'
        },
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
    },
    devServer: {
        disableHostCheck: true,
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        hot: true,
        port: 3000,
        publicPath: `/themes/${DISTRIBUTION_FOLDER}/`,
        proxy: {
            '/': {
                'target': {
                    'host': `${SITE_NAME}`,
                    'protocol': 'http',
                    'port': 80
                },
                changeOrigin: true,
                secure: false
            }
        },
        stats: 'errors-only'
    },
    plugins: plugins
};
```

```
the full package can be found here:

https://github.com/sunnysideup/silverstripe-sswebpack_engine_only
I want to be able to run `npm run build` without errors

My environment:

node version: 8.0.0

npm version: 5.5.1

ubuntu 16.04

cms: silverstripe

Comment: I am still looking for a solution ...

Comment: have you seen this: https://github.com/vue-bulma/datepicker/issues/45

Comment: Thank you for sharing @OlliTyynelä - I dont use that date picker so I dont think that is directly related.

Comment: Umm.. it wasn't about the date picker it was about the similarity of the  punc error that could be caused by the arrow function

Answer (score 3):

If you're explicitly adding the `UglifyJSPlugin()`, your use of the `-p` flag is redundant, and is probably causing a conflict where the uglification is happening before the ES6 transpiling (as your `punc()` error indicates).

Probable solution: Just use `NODE_ENV=production webpack`. You're detecting the `production` environment variable in your config and handling it the way you want to already. Letting webpack do its own production build on top of that is probably tripping things up.

Comment: Thank you Uncle!  I tried this and it partially works.  I now only see the error once rather than twice: the first of the two errors seems to have been resolved!  How can I resolve the second one?  The weird thing is that it was all working up to a week ago.  We have run npm install a few times since.  Should we have a look at the differences in packages in the last week?

Comment: `rm -rf node_modules/ && npm install` is always a good thing to try. you may have multiple versions of UglifyJS.

Answer (score 1):

While Uncle Cheese provided half the answer, here is the other half:

webpack.config.babel.js, a change from:
...

```
plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
);
```

to

```
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

plugins.push(
    new UglifyJSPlugin(),
);
```

fixes it... YES - thank you !

Here is what I now use in package.json:

```
"uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
```